# Two or more slashes after server name - mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have small problem with this:
http://server//file

How can I delete this two slashes? I try to do it which this method:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/{2,}$ [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R,L]
```

But it doesn't works.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# hide .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# remove multi trailing slashes, for simple x/y/ => x/y
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R,L]

# remove more than one slashes when they are in link, for simple x//y => x/y
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R,L]

# rewrite all links server/x to server/x.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).* $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# hide .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# remove multi trailing slashes, for simple x/y/ => x/y
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R,L]

# remove more than one slashes when they are in link, for simple x//y => x/y
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1 [R,L,NE]

# rewrite all links server/x to server/x.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I have problem with links like: server/file/anothervalue. Can you solve it? :) I'm thinking about it but I'm too stupid :/

Comment: My code works with: http://server/file//value//more//// but not works with http://server///file/value, when I write http://server//file//value it's changed to server/file/value, but when it's only server///file it's not changed.

Comment: Yes, it's correctly redirecting from http://domain.com///////fooobar to http://domain.com/foobar but from http://domain.com///////fooobar/bar to http://domain.com/fooobar/bar not :) but thanks again, i will try do it yourself.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, i know how it works. It searches in foobar folder the bar.php file, but i want something like that: SERVER/FILE/PARAMS/PARMAS, not SERVER/DIRECTORY/FILE :) so domain/file redirect to file.php and domain/file/param redierct to file.php too. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should convert the two slashes (or more) into one:

```
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} \ (.*)//+(.*)\  
    RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R,L]
```